# How to print new line in nested list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Am the new one to python. I want to display the possibilities of two dices using list comprehension. I got the output. But is it possible to print new line when y reaches 6(y==6)?

My coding:

```
d1=(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
d2=(1,2,3,4,5,6) 
print([(x,y) for x in d1 for y in d2])
```

My Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

My Expectation output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), 
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), 
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), 
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), 
(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), 
(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print has an optional parameter `end`
This is normally a new line but you can modify it so that it is a space or whatever you want. You can use this to recreate your needed output:

```
d1=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
d2=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
# this is bad style and should be avoided because of side effects (see comments)
([print((x,y), end='\n' if y==len(d2) else ' ') for x in d1 for y in d2])
```

Better without side effects:

```
for tup in [(x,y) for x in d1 for y in d2]:
    print(tup, end='\n' if tup[1]==len(d2) else ' ')
```

Output:

```
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) (1, 5) (1, 6)
(2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) (2, 5) (2, 6)
(3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) (3, 5) (3, 6)
(4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4) (4, 5) (4, 6)
(5, 1) (5, 2) (5, 3) (5, 4) (5, 5) (5, 6)
(6, 1) (6, 2) (6, 3) (6, 4) (6, 5) (6, 6)
```

And in case you really want a authentic list output (with all the special character (",", "[", "]") then you can do this as well with a bit more work:

```
def print_nice_list(d1,d2):
    print("[",end="")
    for tup in [(x,y) for x in d1 for y in d2]:
        end = ", "
        if tup[1] == len(d2) and tup[0]==len(d1):
            end = "]"
        elif tup[1] == len(d2):
            end = ",\n"
        print(tup, end=end )

print_nice_list(d1,d2)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6),
(2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6),
(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6),
(6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

Edit: Reworked the answer based on the comments.

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. I am learning list comprehension now. I still have some doubt in, what the code means " print((x,y), end='\n' if y==6 else ' ') ". Because When I studied about list comprehension, it tells expression will come first. Here it is different. If you have time, kindly explain this.

Comment: The list comprehension builds a list of `None` values returned by the print calls, not pythonic unfortuantely

Comment: Using list comprehensions for side effects (`([print((x,y), end='\n' if y==6 else ' ') for x in d1 for y in d2])` is considered bad style.

Comment: Also, in `print_nice_list()`, you shouldn't harcode the boundary values (`6` in this case) but use the lengths of the arguments (`d1` and `d2`) instead.

Comment: @user3661367 What I do is bad style but I will explain it to you anyway. The expression is first but the whole expression is print((x,y), end='\n' if y==len(d2) else ' ')  and in this expression I have an inline if else condition which will change the end parameter if a new line is needed or not.

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for visualization, you should use `pprint`:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> lst = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
>>> pprint.pprint(lst, compact=True, width=50)
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6),
 (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6),
 (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6),
 (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6),
 (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6),
 (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```